# How to create Security group In SharePoint 2013

Tags: security

In **SharePoint Online** we have group called Security group.

Please see the image below.

[image]

I have to create **Security Group** in SharePoint 2013 (On-premise).

How can I create **Security Group**?

What is **Security Group**?

Comment: It looks like you're saying, "Here's how I do this in SharePoint Online (picture). I need to do the same thing in SharePoint 2013, how do I do it?" Am I understanding that correctly? If so, I believe this question needs the [tag:2013] tag. The existing answer appears to give instructions for SP Online, based on the image.

Answer (score 1):

To add security group please follow below steps.

Navigate to Groups > Groups.

TIP: You can also enter text similar to **add security group** into the Tell me what you want to do ... search box and the **New Group** dialog will open if you choose **Add a group** from the Tasks list.

[image]

On the **Groups** page, choose **Add a group**.

In the **Type** drop-down, choose Security group

Type a name and description for the group, and then choose **Add > Close**.

To add members, select the Security group on the **Groups** page and choose **Edit members** on the **Bulk** **actions for groups selected** dialog.

Type the name of the person you want to add in the **Search** box and then choose **Add**.

To remove members choose **Remove** next to their name.

```
Your next question
```

**What is Security group?**

You can manage users of SharePoint sites more efficiently if you assign permission levels to groups instead of to individual users. A SharePoint group is a set of individual users and can also include Active Directory Domain Services (AD DS) groups

Please visit the below link for more.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc261972.aspx

Answer (score 0):

A security group is really more of an Active Directory thing than a SharePoint thing (assuming you're using AD). In AD, a security group is a group which can be used to assign permissions through discretionary access control lists. In SharePoint, permissions can be assigned to AD security groups, and AD security groups can be indirectly assigned permissions by adding them as members to SharePoint Groups.

The other type of AD group is called a Distribution List, which is more like an email alias. They cannot be used to assign permissions (in or out of SharePoint) and cannot be added as members to SharePoint groups.

So the answer to your question is, you create a security group in Active Directory.

Ref: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/sites/overview-of-security-groups-in-sharepoint-server